# Invoking method issue in Java

Tags: java

```
public class Tester {

    private String text;

    public void text() {
        text = "abc";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tester test = new Tester();
        System.out.println(test.text);
    }
}
```

Why does this print `null`? Also, if I write `test.text()` inside the print command, why there is an error? I thought I needed to invoke the method like that.

Comment: because you have not assigned text as you have not called text() method. So the default value is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` because `private String text;` is `null` as you have not made call to your `public void text()` which sets the value of `String text`

Make call to your `text()` before printing

```
Tester test=new Tester();
test.text();
System.out.println(test.text);
```

*Output:*

```
abc
```

***PS.***

As per comment => *"Can I directly write System.out.println(test.text())? "*

For that set `return` type to `String` and return `String` from it

So Change your code  to

```
public String text() {
        return "abc";    
    }
```

And

```
Test test = new Test();
System.out.println(test.text());
```

*Output:*

```
abc
```

Comment: Hi Tarsem， it works, thank you, so why do i need to write like this, I understand test.text() is calling the method, but what does test.text mean in the print?

Comment: `test.text` means you are accessing `private String text;` from class `Tester` by making its object test.  and you can't access the `private String text;` without object of class. if you want to access without making object of class `Tester` then you can change declaration to `private static String text;`

Comment: Can I directly write System.out.println(test.text())?

Comment: @peiwang No, as that means print out whatever returns from my function , since it returns void or nothing then it causes your exception or it doesn't compile.

Comment: @peiwang To do that, `test.text()` would need to return a `String`, while it currently doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thank you Tarsem, basically, I do not think public void text() {
        text = "abc";
    } is a proper way to define a method, method with "void" should  always have System.out.print in the method body, otherwise, it will cause mistake or confusion in the main() method

Comment: @peiwang it depends on your logics how you construct/implement them... good luck ahead...:)

Answer (score 0):

It is printing null because the default value of all Class types is null, you have not set text and still trying to print. 
if you want to print abc then follow either of the following ways

> 1 call you text method explicitly like test.text();
>
> 2 initialize yourtext in constructor as follows

```
Tester(){
text="abc";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your String object is assigned `null` at construction time - that is, when you declare `new Tester()`, your `text` field is assigned `null`.  This is the default value of all object types, and all primitives are assigned zero (or false, if the primitive is a boolean).

Nothing's assigned to it, and the default behavior of printing out `null` is to print the literal text `"null"`.

As for your second question - the reason that this won't work:

```
System.out.println(test.text());
```

`text()` is a method call that returns `void`, or nothing.  There's nothing that is returned as a result of the method call, so nothing can be printed out.

You would want to move your call to `text()` before any print statements, so the field is properly populated:

```
Tester test = new Tester();
test.text();
System.out.println(test.text);
```

...and, there is a convention for something like this:  if you want the field to be populated at construction time, create a constructor that accepts it as an argument.

```
public Tester(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}
```

When you construct it, you don't need to worry about any extraneous call to `text()`; just print the field.

```
Tester test = new Tester("abc");
System.out.println(test.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `test.text()；` firstly to give test a value.

Answer (score 0):

As `text` is a class variable so it is by default initialized to null.If it would be `int` then it would have been initialized to 0;

In your program you are not calling `text()` so the value of text is not changed.Now in the main method you are printing text so its printing `null`;

*Also, if I write test.text() inside the print command, why there is an error?*

this is because the return type of `text()` is void